# Can influenza spread to other countries?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

When you get the Influenza event, you have two choices:

- Quarantine the port and let the die!
- This is not the first flu in our country, I don't care!

If I don't care, there's a 75% chance of spreading to neighboring provinces. Does this include neighboring provinces owned by other countries, or does the flu respect borders?

Comment: Shut. Down. Everything.

Comment: The flu respects international borders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quote from the wiki on this:

> Option: This is not the first flu in our country, I don't care!:
>
> The owner of the province: Changes administrative power stored by -5
>   Adds the modifier "Influenza" until the end of the campaign:
>   province_trade_power_modifier = -1.0
>   -50% manpower modifier
>   -50% provincial tax income
>   -50% trade goods output
>
> If: Limited to: Any bordering province: **The province is owned by our country**
>
> Does not have the province modifier "Quarantined Influenza" 
>   Does not have the province modifier "Influenza" 
>   Randomized by Acquisition chance: Random bordering province:
>
> Limited to: **The province is owned by our country** 
>   Does not have the province modifier "Quarantined Influenza" 
>   Does not have the province modifier "Influenza"

I have in the past chosen the "Don't care" option a couple of times and I can confirm that my flu has never crossed into another country.